Windows 11 system corrupted? no WU, no in-place reinstall, no SFC, no DISM, …
Trying to update the Nvidia drivers to the latest 552.44 I realized my Windows installation is royally crippled...

First.

The drivers installation failed. And then it suddenly removed the 552.22 version I had installed, removed the RTX 4080 device in Device Manager, created a "VGA compatible" basic device instead and switch my resolution to 1024x768...

Trying to update/change the driver for that "VGA device" detects it is the RTX 4080, but ANY driver installation says "Access denied", no matter it is from the Device Manager or any Nvidia installer, no matter it is autodetected or a manual .inf...



Next.

Going back to a previous Macrium backup only showed me that I've been using a 'corrupted' system for some time:

Windows Update does not work, there are ALWAYS errors:


Reinstallation do not work, the option is not even available:


SFC /scannow do not work:

DISM /online /cleanup-image /RestoreHealth do not work either:


dism.log: https://pastebin.com/WRWaYSMz

Trying to install ANY Windows version on top do not work, not even any Insider builds, 24H2 or whatever... they ALL fail:




This is from the same Windows.11.Professional.23H2.22631.3447.EN-US.X64 I already have installed:

22631.3527.240416-1719.23H2_NI_RELEASE_SVC_PROD3_CLIENTPRO_OEMRET_X64FRE_EN-US says exactly the same.
And this is from 26100.1.240331-1435.GE_RELEASE_CLIENTPRO_OEMRET_X64FRE_EN-US:

Promising, but shortly after...

It doesn't even get to the restart step.
Tried many 'Repair' and 'Fix' softwares and tools like WURESET ( https://wureset.com ), etc... and none did anything at all...
Also, tried downloading the KB5036980 update ( windows11.0-kb5036980-x64_6bfd0dfab47b1e42a5235ebff07e37700b72269c.msu ) directly from Microsoft Update Catalog ( https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5036980 ) and when I run it...

It's like every single thing I try is a "Nope. Fudge you, pal... ¯_(ツ)_/¯ "
Any suggestions? If I have to clean install a Windows 11 and spend like a week reinstalling and reconfiguring every software, app and tool I have installed I'm not going to be happy.

Since you got backups, run this from PowerShell: https://pastebin.com/00ybA8vE reboot, and then try again. Might also wipe any obsolete or unneeded profiles from sysdm.cpl | Advanced | User profiles | Settings and wipe any old or unnecessary profiles from there. Reboot after all that too, and try again.

It appears you are running an Insider Preview build. What build are you running? You can determine this by running “winver”, provide the relevant information, by editing your questions. A solution to your problem is possible. All I need to provide one is that build information. Provide a screenshot of the Insider Preview tab within Settings

It's not an Insider build, it's Windows 11 Pro 23H2 22631.3447

@Bombadil - 22631.3447 Absolutely is an Insider Preview build, specifically, part of the Release Preview Channel. You are 100% about the build? That’s exactly what winver indicated and what about the tab in Settings? Setup Diag log is also required

@John - Your answer to the authors problem was to reinstall Windows, that’s not helpful, the author could have decided to do that without our help. You decided to delete your answer. Nobody forced you to do that. Don’t act like a victim because your answer is now deleted. You say it’s “all you can do” but I know that to be false since I solved this very issue myself for myself. Now i didn’t have the WU issue, but I had the issue where I could keep my files, and that’s because I was trying to downgrade the build. Been there solved it.

@Ramhound  Mmmm...   really? I wasn't aware at all about that. I think I installed an update from the Microsoft Update Catalog a while back, but never joined the Insider Preview Program from the Windows Update settings page.
This is what it says now about it: https://i.postimg.cc/fL5FQW6P/image.png
I guess because I have TPM and Secure Boot disabled (installed a patched ISO originally).
Here is the CBS.log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17UBoudYCxC8pdXWR8uIAlVHBq9QbVaFK/view?usp=sharing

When I run SetupDiag.exe /Output:C:\SetupDiag\Results.txt it freezes at "SetupDiag: processing rule: DebugSetupCrash." step...

@John I did a clean install of 22631.3527 and it works ok, Nvidia driver then installs ok and everything looks fine... but that leaves me with a barenaked OS and like a full week of installing and configuring apps, programs, tools, ... a huge pain in the arse process that I would prefer not to suffer.
So yeah, clean install would be like the very last resort in case everything else fails and nobody has any idea how to fix this.

I don't wanna be ungrateful, but I totally agree with @Ramhound here...   I did all that yesterday. I wouldn't be asking anything here for an answer like "Just do a clean install of Windows"...

@John - You downloaded a specific Windows 11 build ISO, identical to that of the build that’s running, in order to NOT attempt to downgrade or upgrade the install and as a result keeping all files on the system? Alright, fine, submit your answer. You should undelete your answer cause I won’t e submitting one.

@Ramhound SetupDiag took a long time but it finished:
SetupDiag: processing rule: DebugSetupCrash.
..DebugSetupCrash - Found qualifying memory dump during setup, but the debugger binaries were not found. Either examine the memory dump here: C:\Windows\Panther\UnattendGC\mndEDB2.diagerr.mdmp or install the debugger tools from here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ to determine the failure.
SetupDiag found 1 matching issue.
These are the log files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ZWtofPZan9UUaatgRtKzRlH10BcnQ2G/view?usp=sharing

@Bombadil - John will help you.

Might be worth a shot—since you got a backup image—if applicable, enabled TPM and/or Secure boot. Get that all worked out then try the Windows Update, etc.

If I activate Secure Boot now Windows do not boot. Enabling TPM makes no difference.

Might have to format to format MBR to GPT first as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt mbr2gpt.exe /validate /disk:0 where disk:0 is the number correlating on your system, assuming it will be 0 though. Then follow that by mbr2gpt /convert /allowFullOS but there may be an override parameter you will need if you get an error. Since you have backups, might be worth a shot once you iron that out. There is also some LabConfig reg keys that used to allow Win 11 upgrade from Win 10 to bypass TPM, might be worth a google search too.

I already used the Labconfig keys and a Skip_TPM_Check_on_Dynamic_Update.cmd since a long time ago. That's not the problem, because I can install a fresh Windows 11 and everything works fine then.

k, check the other commands I mentioned as well. Out of ideas if you are already GPT formatted, I'm in the same boat with some Windows 10 VMs so getting TPM settings straightened out before I see if I can upgrade them or not once I do that. I too can install fresh Windows 11 without TPM on that specific platform with similar issues but I assume it's something along those same line with that specific update. Good luck regardless!
